# Iptables: redirect marked traffic to another interface

Tags: iptables

I have a config which redirects all marked packets to a proxy server listening on   port 1082 and it works:

```
ipset create unblock hash:net -exist
iptables -I PREROUTING -w -t nat -i br0 -p tcp -m set --match-set unblock dst -j REDIRECT --to-port 1082
iptables -I PREROUTING -w -t nat -i br0 -p udp -m set --match-set unblock dst -j REDIRECT --to-port 1082
```

I also have a Wireguard interface (ngw0) with IP address 172.16.0.2 on port 48950. What i'm trying to do is redirect those packets to wireguard interface. Tried soulitons:

```
ipset create unblock hash:net -exist
iptables -I PREROUTING -w -t nat -i br0 -p tcp -m set --match-set unblock dst -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.0.2:48950
iptables -I PREROUTING -w -t nat -i br0 -p udp -m set --match-set unblock dst -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.0.2:48950
```

And

```
ipset create unblock hash:net -exist
iptables -I PREROUTING -w -t nat -i br0 -p tcp -m set --match-set unblock dst -j MASQUERADE -o nwg0
iptables -I PREROUTING -w -t nat -i br0 -p udp -m set --match-set unblock dst -j MASQUERADE -o nwg0
```

None of these works.How do I redirect traffic to Wireguard?

UPD:

```
ip addr show br0
24: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip addr show nwg0
27: nwg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1324 qdisc noqueue qlen 50
    link/[65534] 
    inet 172.16.0.2/32 scope global nwg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


~ # netstat -an | grep 48950
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48950           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 :::48950                :::*
~ # netstat -an | grep 1082
tcp        0      0 :::1082                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.0.1:1082 ::ffff:192.168.0.130:56540 TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: Does your ipset "unblock" have any entries in it (e.g. as seen with "ipset list")?

Comment: @DericS yes it does, Name: unblock
Type: hash:net
Revision: 6
Header: family inet hashsize 4096 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 219868
References: 2
Members:
5.35.171.32/27
89.22.128.0/18
95.215.124.0/22

Comment: Are you trying to intercept a Wireguard session and make it work (e.g. with encryption) with your system as some sort of proxy Wireguard peer end point?  Or maybe you just want regular packets (i.e. that have nothing to do with a Wireguard connection) to be sent to the IP associated with your Wireguard interface?  Could be useful to add to the question, the output of commands like: "ip addr show br0", "ip addr show ngw0", "wg show" (don't include the private in the output unless this is just a test environment).

Comment: @DericS it's the second option. Added the output of the first two commands, the second one says wg not found. Just to clarify, it's a router UNIX-like OS (KeeneticOS)

Comment: How do you know this is not working?  Or perhaps easier to answer: What are you expecting to see in order to know if it works?  If port 48950 is your Wireguard port (I was hoping to confirm that with the output of "wg show"), then maybe the redirect is working but Wireguard is just dropping the packets because they are not part of a valid Wireguard encrypted session.  I'll make a bunch of assumptions and suggest that you try to remove the ":48950" from your "-j DNAT" entries and see what happens.

Comment: @DericS i will know that it works when i visit one of specified resources from the 'unblock' ipset and it shows me that i have the ip address leased by wireguard server, not by my provider. wireguard connection works for sure, i tried setting it up as the primary connection on my router and then ALL resources show me i have the wireguard's IP. Tried removing ":48950" from your "-j DNAT", nothing changed

Comment: If KeeneticOS has the "ss" or "netstat" tools, can you add to the question, the output of either "ss -ln sport = 48950" and "ss -ln sport = 1082" or "netstat -an | grep 48950" and "netstat -an | grep 1082"?  In the meantime, I'll make some more assumptions and suggest that you change ":48950" to ":1082" in your "-j DNAT" entries and see what happens.  It's not quite clear to me what "Wireguard" has to do with your setup, since you just seem to be trying to use the Wireguard IP address, but none of the WG VPN capabilities, in which case, why not put the WG IP address on a regular interface?

Comment: @DericS added netstat output. Changing the port doesn't change anything. What do you mean by  put the WG IP address on a regular interface? What I'm trying to achieve is redirect marked packets (--match-set unblock) to intergace nwg0 (172.16.0.2:48950), currently they are just redirected to port 1082 which is listened by shadowsocks client

Comment: When you write "setting it up as the primary connection on my router and then ALL resources show me i have the wireguard's IP", was that done without any NAT configuration?  Maybe what you are looking for is more of a routing configuration instead of an iptables NAT configuration.  The output of "ip rule show" and "ip route show table all" could be useful if added to the question.